# Flask request.get_json() returns string not json

Tags: python, json, flask

using `Flask 1.0.2` on `Windows` and `Python 3.6 64bit`
first i send data via `jquery` `ajax` call, which on JS side is valid `json`

```
var myData = '{ "id": "' +clickedID +'" }'
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //content type
    url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/colors/delete', //Where to make Ajax calls
    dataType:'json', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
    processData: false,
    data:JSON.stringify(myData), 
});
```

in flask I catch the POST request and try to parse it:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    print("got request method POST")
if request.is_json:
    print("is json")
    data_json = request.get_json(force=True)
    data_req = request.data
    print("{} is {}".format(data_req, type(data_req)))
    print("{} is {}".format(data_json, type(data_json)))
    data_json2 = json.loads(request.get_json(silent=True, force=True))
    print("{} is {}".format(data_json2, type(data_json2)))
    print (request.json.keys())
```

with the result:

```
got request: POST
is json
b'"{ \\"id\\": \\"1\\" }"' is <class 'bytes'>
{ "id": "1" } is <class 'str'>
{'id': '1'} is <class 'dict'>
print (request.json.keys())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @RakeshSharma did that :) thx for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In overview, you serialise an object to JSON, which is in effect a string, POST it using the JSON data type, then deserialise it to get the object back. Some objects are easy to serialise and de-serialise with off the shelf functions). See an example based your code modified below (Ignore the CORS as that's due to my test evironment set up).

```
import logging, json
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/api",methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    logging.info('hello')
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("got request method POST")
    if request.is_json:
        print("is json")
        data = request.get_json()
        print("type of data {}".format(type(data))) # type dict
        print("data as string {}".format(json.dumps(data)))
        print ("keys {}".format(json.dumps(data.keys())))
    return jsonify(message='success')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

<html>
    <style>
    </style>
    <button onClick="_ajax()">POST</button>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        const url_path = "http://localhost:5000/api";
        function _ajax() {
            console.log('_ajax called');
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var clickedID="testClickedID";
            var myData = {"id": clickedID};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //content type
                url: url_path, //Where to make Ajax calls
                dataType:'json', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                processData: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(myData), 
            }).done(
                function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            );
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I get `type str` still here - `print("type of data {}".format(type(data)))` No idea why.

Answer (score 8):

`JSON.stringify()` takes a Javascript object and turns it into a JSON string. You're not passing it an object, you're passing it a string, which is then converted into JSON again.

Because the request data contains double-encoded JSON, the `request.json` attribute gives you back a string rather than a dictionary.

To fix, change:

```
var myData = '{ "id": "' +clickedID +'" }'
```

to:

```
var myData = { id: clickedID }
```